# Javascript function always returns true?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I have this function which is a property of an object,

```
Layer.prototype.mouseInBounds = function() {

    // Return value
    var ret = true;
    // Layer mouse co-ordinates are not valid
    if (this.mouse.x < 0 || this.mouse.y < 0 || this.mouse.x >= this.width || this.mouse.y >= this.height) {
        // Set layer mouse co-ordinates to false
        this.mouse.x = false;
        this.mouse.y = false;
        // Set return value
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
};
```

But when I call it like so from within another object that has the layer as a property,

```
this.layer.mouseInBounds() // true
```

No matter what the value of `ret` inside of the `mouseInBounds` function?

**EDIT**

To better understand my question `mouse` is a property of layer, and when adding

```
console.log(ret);
```

Just before the return statement I do indeed get either `true` or `false`,

Comment: What is `this` (`Layer`)? What is `this.mouse`?  Have you tried to check the `.x` and `.y` values to make sure they are correct?

Comment: have you debugged that code?

Comment: You are going to need more context here

Comment: It is a property of the layer,

Comment: `console.log(this.mouse.x, this.mouse.y, this.width, this.height)` Basic debugging.

Comment: When debugging, where did you put the mouse cursor?

Comment: Why the downvotes, a general question that I am stuck with?!?!

Comment: Maybe because there is nothing obviously wrong with your code and we cannot run your code. So the problem lies somewhere we have no information about. There is not really a lot we can do and it's probably not very useful for future visitors. [See this article to learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners). To get better help, I recommend to create a minimal http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I will try to ask better questions in the future. Thanks

Comment: Also, as a tip for your code in the future, it looks like you're using `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` to represent both numerical values as well as boolean values. I'd recommend just sticking to one type. While you can change the type of a variable in JavaScript, it's not generally a good idea to do so.

Answer (score 1):

It always returns `true` because:

- `this.mouse.x < 0` is always `false`, and
- `this.mouse.y < 0` is always `false`, and
- `this.mouse.x >= this.width` is always `false`, and
- `this.mouse.y >= this.height` is always `false`

I don't know what `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` specifically represent, but if they're x/y mouse coordinates measured from the top-left corner of the window, then I don't know how they could be less than `0`.